# "All My Files" in Finder of Lion has stopped working

Tags: macos, finder

"All My Files" in Finder of Lion has stopped working.[image]

I suspect that this has happened after installing Path Finder 5.7.8.

Comment: What exactly do you mean my "All My Files"?

Comment: @daviesgeek - I tried posting image but it is not allowing me as for posting image one would require more than 10 reputation. I humbly request see a video of this on Youtube.

Comment: Now you can post it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are correct regarding Path Finder being the culprit :). Cocoatech's [Path Finder Changelog](http://www.cocoatech.com/changelog) lists this in it's most recent version (5.8.8):

> Fixed All Files search item in Lion and other saved searches.

Updating Path Finder should resolve this issue.

Comment: The changelog says 5.8.8 is the latest version, yet the download link, and the OP says 5.7.8. I'm terribly confused and I suspect a typo somewhere.

Regardless, the answer to this question is: Update Path Finder, if not now, then whenever it is available.